# Chattering weird noise!

Tags: cats, behavior, vocalizations

My 1year old cat has started to chatter makes a weird movement with his mouth, mainly when hes doing nothing!  Not like hes seen something to catch, the total opposite!
Could this be anything to worry about?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This sounds like the chattering at bugs that cats seem to be genetically programmed to do. You can probably find a video of it quite easily by searching for "cat chattering at fly" or somesuch. And just because you can't see something edible, doesn't mean the cat can't.

Comment: According to the linked question, it is mild frustration :)

Comment: i want you to know different cats chatter for different reasons,and they can often start or stop to chatter at what we might see as random times.it is simply not possible to make an answer that fully explains a cat`s vocal comunication.

Answer (score 1):

I've always heard of this as "charming." My cats do it all of the time if they see a bird. They hunch down and make a soft kind of broken meow. I don't know if it's an old wives tale, but my Grandmother told me that the cat is trying to mimic the bird noises to lull it into a false sense of security.

Comment: Yea, they also make a clicking noise by chomping on their teeth hard. I've seen them do it at prey and other cats/dogs; even sort of barking like a dog. Lots of licking and weird sorts of singing and stuff. Recently there have been some youtube videos remixing the meowing with beats and stuff. Cats make some pretty interesting sounds.